# C++: initializing variables; overloading implicit constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization

I want to reimplement a library of which I have the header file.
I would prefer not to change the .h file since that would require changes in the programs that use the library (plus some legal reasons).
EDIT: I also cannot change the code that uses the library and instantiates class X!

the lib.h defines a class X (simplified version):

```
class X 
{
public:
    bool Function(BOOL q, INT p);
    BOOL a;
    INT b;
};
```

(BOOL and INT are just some datatypes used by the library, these classes wrap a primitive data type of bool and int).

I implemented this class in my_lib_implementation.cpp:

```
bool X::Function(BOOL q, INT p)
{
    return true;
}
```

The .h file does not define a constructor, so this means that there is an implicit constructor (right?).
Problem is, I need to initialise the variables a and b for my implementation of Function(BOOL q, INT p) to work correctly.
However if I add the following, I get compile errors ("error: definition of implicitly-declared 'X::X()'", gcc 4.4):

```
X::X()
{
    a=true;
    b=0;
}
```

Is it possible to overload the constructor through some magic that I do not know about? Are there other options for initializing the variables?
There is a an implementation of the library (that I can't use), so it seems like it should be possible somehow?

I only just started programming C++ this week (I do have extensive experience with other languages), so this problem is probably just my lack of basic knowledge.
Hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible, the compiler-generated default constructor cannot be overloaded.

You can however initialize the members with the following syntax:

```
X x = {true, 0};
```

Comment: Is this standard-documented btw? I know of this hack, afaik it works on most compilers worth knowing of and I kindof know why, but is this defined behavior?

Comment: @TC1 it's not a hack, it's a language feature. It's been around since C, and it's safe to use.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my question. I can't really change the code that calls the library either.

Comment: @user1302914 then what you want is impossible.

Comment: Ok that ain't nice. I just thought of a backup plan: Could I call a static function (let's call it Z) from my X::Function(BOOL, INT) implementation that keeps track whether that X object has been initialized already? if not then x::Function(BOOL, INT) can initialize first before starting the regular execution. Only Z would have to be able to differntiate between the different X instance, that however seems possible in C, by using the address of a variable?? I know it is terribly inefficient (the function would get called millions of times :() But would a scheme like that work??

Comment: @user1302914 how would you tell if the members were initialized correctly?

Comment: I thought I would be able to distinguish different X objects in function Z by their this pointer. I was foolish and forgot that different objects on the stack are very likely to have the same address at different times. So you are right: no go.

Comment: you were the first to say what I wanted was impossible :(, so marked your answer as correct (unless someone else comes with a brilliant idea of course). Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a way to directly do what you're asking.  (Provide a default constructor without declaring it in the class.)

The closest you can come to this is to also redefine the `BOOL` and `INT` classes, assuming those have defined default constructors.  If they have, then you can change the meaning of the default to whatever you want.

Alternately, you could completely change the behavior of the function.  You can add members to the class, including for example something to keep track of whether the function has been called yet, or how many times, etc.  Or you could define your own `betterthanX` member and just forward the function calls to the member, and then copy out the results back into the members of the real X class.

Comment: hadn't thought about this! but no go either. BOOL and INT have implicit constructors too.

Answer (score 1):

A very dirty hack could be to define a preprocessor macro just before including the library header file that changes X to X_. You can then define your own X that inherits from X_ and defines whatever constructor you like. You should `#undef` the macro after the `#include`. Don't blame me if you run into insidious bugs.

Comment: This might work but it depends whether when the question says "can't change the code that calls it" it means that the code can be recompiled but not edited, or that it is binary only.  Obviously this won't work if the code that uses it is provided only in compiled form.

Comment: I'm unsure if this crosses the line to explicitly changing the library (which OP says has legal implication).

Comment: @SoapBox Well, you don't have to change any code. You could do this in a `.h` file that's named the same as the library `.h` file. You then only need to manipulate the include path. If the code is provided in compiled form, nothing will work, since constructors will probably have been inlined.

Comment: @pmr I'm sorry, I'm unable to care about legal stuff, when it comes to code :)

Comment: @enobayram I took "can't change the code" to mean "don't have the actual source code, only have a binary".  Your answer requires all of the calling code to be recompiled with the new header.  If the calling "code" is supplied only as a pre-compiled shared library or executable then there might be no way to do it.  It depends WHY the calling code can't be changed.

Comment: @SoapBox with that interpretation, I have to agree that it's simply impossible. The linker will not even be looking for the `X::X()` symbol.

Comment: I do have the source code of the program, but I don't want to change it.
I should explain a bit more: The program is supposed to run on an embedded device. I want to simulate the execution on a regular x86 PC. There are library implementations for both the embedded device as well as the PC. 
I however want to use my own library because I want to test specific things during the execution. I don't want to change the code of the program itself, because I want to test the exact code that will run on the embedded device. I should be able to compile the exact same code for the embedded device.

Comment: I rather not change the .h file, because I am not sure what the license is. Whether it has just been made available, or whether I can actually change it and make copies of that. The people here already have copies of the original .h file, so I won't have to distribute that if I don't change anything. Edit: This is all for a school research project, but I am not sure about 'fair use' in my copyright jurisdiction. I hope this explain my complicated side-conditions to the problem :)

Comment: @user1302914 then the macro trick could work for you. You don't touch the original `.h` file, you just include it in your impostor `.h` file

Comment: Enobayrum: you are right. I tried your suggestion and it worked! Then I found out I was an idiot, because it broke the build of the original application (I was working with my unit tests before). Turns out the application did use X x = {true, ..}; to initialise, but I looked in the wrong place and didn't find it before. Recap: the whole problem didn't exist. Your method solved it :)